# When does `decltype` with a function call expression require the function to be defined?

Tags: templates, c++11, clang, sfinae, decltype

In clang I get this warning

```
warning: inline function 'detail::selector<2, int>::select' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
    static constexpr auto select(T const&) -> std::integral_constant<int, Which>;
                          ^

note: used here
static_assert( decltype(Selector::select(int()))::value == 2, "");
                                  ^
```

in the code below.

Is NOT defining the function here harmful? (I strongly believe, it doesn't matter here and in my application, since it's used in unevaluated context, in std::enable_if).

Now, I'm wondering *when* the compiler thinks it should issue a warning.

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

    template <int Which, typename...> struct selector;

    template <int Which>
    struct selector<Which> {
        static constexpr void select();  // never select
    };

    template <int Which, typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct selector<Which, T, Ts...> : selector<Which+1, Ts...>
    {
        using selector<Which+1, Ts...>::select;
        static constexpr auto select(T const&) -> std::integral_constant<int, Which>;
    };
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using Selector = detail::selector<0, char, short, int>;
    static_assert( decltype(Selector::select(int()))::value == 2, "");    
    return 0;
}
```

#### Edit:

Notes:

- gcc-4.8.1 on ideone.com does not issue a warning.
- The simplest way to get rid of the warning is providing an implementation, e.g.:

  ```
  static constexpr auto select(T const&) 
  -> std::integral_constant<int, Which> 
  { return {}; }
  ```

  (thanks @Yakk)

---

**Solution**:

As explained in the answer provided by [@Filip Roséen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090079) the `constexpr` specifier will implicitly declare that function inline, which requires a definition WHEN it is evaluated. The function is *not* used in my code, though - but nonetheless clang will issue that warning (indicating a minor issue in the compiler). clang will not issue this warning anymore, when the `constexpr` specifier is omitted. The `constexpr` specifier seems to be inappropriate anyway, (thanks [@Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk)).

Comment: It's interesting it complains about `detail::selector<2, int>::select` when that's not the real name of the function.  The instantiation of `using selector<Which+1, Ts...>::select;` is a redeclaration of the same function `constexpr void selector<3>::select();`, not a different function.

Comment: @aschepler I don't follow

Comment: @CouchDeveloper why `constexpr` if it has no implementation?

Comment: @Yakk It's probably superfluous. The actual implementation where I extracted this demo snippet does implement it, e.g.: `constexpr Result<Which, T> select(T const&) { return Result<Which, T>(); }`

Comment: @CouchDeveloper why not `return {}`?

Comment: @Yakk That would be even better! I hadn't thought of this. Code is from (my) C++ days 1 1/2 years ago. But returning a brace-init-list would be a simple workaround, _Result_ is an aggregate with no members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**Note**; as stated the diagnostic issued by *clang* is a mere warning and not an error, which means that it's just there to attract our attention to a segment which might be misused if not handled correctly.</sup>

---

**What might potentially go wrong?**

Entities marked as *constexpr* are implicitly `inline` (which is also true for functions defined directly within a class), as stated in `[dcl.fct.spec]p3`.

Functions having the `inline` specifier, implicitly or not, must follow the rules applied to such. The warning issued by *clang* is there to warn developers of writing code that violates the following (among others):

> [**dcl.fct.spec**]
>
> > 4) An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is *odr-used* and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2).

> [**basic.def.odr**]
>
> > 2) An expression is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) ...
> >
> > 3) A variable `x` whose name appears as a *potentially-evaluated* expression `ex` is *odr-used* ...
> >
> > 4) ... An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is *odr-used* and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2).

---

**Is clang correct to issue `-Wundefined-inline` in our context?**

Technically... **No**, the warning is of no value since our usage of `select` doesn't violate the *one definition rule* in an unevaluated context.

You could supress the warning by passing `-Wno-undefined-inline` when invoking *clang*, and if this bothers you greatly please [file a bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/).

Comment: Thank you Filip, this explanation was quite clear and now I understand the problem more thoroughly! That is, the `constexpr` implicitly declares that function `inline`, and an inlined function shall have a definition when it is odr-used. Since the function is not evaluated, clang is too picky. I removed the `constexpr` specifier in the code above, and voilà, clang doesn't issue this warning anymore. (Updated my question with the solution)